# How to create Line Graph in Crystal Report?

Tags: sql-server-2008, crystal-reports-2008

Good day, I want to make a graph base on this results [image: query result]
to graphical representation like this [image: graph]

Is this possible in Crystal Reports ?

Comment: you can use graph options in crystal reports

Comment: @Siva, thank you for your response. yes, i already did. :)
do you know any good tutorials on crystal report ? from basic, intermidiate to pro ? 
tnx :')